# QML How to properly center 2 elements in RowLayout, so that first element is in the middle and second right to it

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a following ColumnLayout:

```
ColumnLayout{
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    spacing: 0.065 * root.height

    id: searchLayout

    SearchTextRow {
        text: qsTr("Search by title")
    }

    InputSearch {
        id: titleText
    }

    RowLayout{

        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter

        SubmitButton {
            id: searchTitleButton

            onClicked:{
                biTitle.running = true;
                recipeFetcher.searchByTitle(titleText.text);
            }
        }

        BusyIndicator{
            scale: Math.min(root.width * 0.002, root.height * 0.002)
            id: biTitle
            running: false
        }
    }
}
```

In RowLayout i would like to position submitbutton and busyindicator in such a way that the submitbutton is perfectly in the middle horizontally, while busyindicator is to the right of it. The following code will treat both of them as one element and center that one element, which is something i don't want.

This is the code for custom SubmitButton class:

```
RoundButton {
    scale: Math.min(root.width * 0.002, root.height * 0.002)
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter

    contentItem: Text {
        text: "Submit"
        color: hovered ? "darkred" : "black"
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        elide: Text.ElideRight
    }

    background: Rectangle {
        opacity: 1
        border.color: "orange"
        radius: parent.radius
        color: "orange"

        layer.enabled: parent.hovered

        layer.effect: DropShadow {
            transparentBorder: true
            color: "orange"
            samples: 40
        }
    }
}
```

There is also another problem, because i would like to scale elements with the resolution of the application, so that they are proportional to the size of the screen.

Assuming i do scale (`scale: Math.min(root.width * 0.002, root.height * 0.002)`) on both or one of the elements, the position will be ruined after the scaling:

On this picture as You can see, centering of submit button and busyindicator is done like they are one same element.
[image]

After scaling both SubmitButton and BusyIndicator this problem arises:

[image]

Comment: Please keep to one question per post. If others have similar questions about scaling, they are less likely to find an answer here if it's hidden within a different question about centering.

Comment: I've not enough experience with QML, but it seems that the layout considers the implicit sizes of items to set their positions, and the items are *then* scaled no matter what. Besides, it seems a bit weird to scale individual items: shouldn't you scale the whole UI instead? That would theoretically solve the issue as its... root ;-)

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting I found an answer, the reason I asked about scaling also is because the solution itself could just solve it aswell, in this case it did. A little bit of weird trickery here with parent-children and this works:

```
RowLayout{

    SubmitButton {

        id: searchIngredientsButton

        onClicked:{
            biSearch.running = true;
        }

        BusyIndicator{
            anchors.left: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.top: parent.top

            anchors.leftMargin: width/10

            id: biSearch
            running: false
        }

   }

}
```

Now BusyIndicator cant be scaled, because the parent already is being scaled, so if we scale busyindicator it will be like double scale kind of.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend *not* setting scale, but, instead, setting either `Layout.width` / `Layout.height` or `implicitWidth`, `implicitHeight` for example:

```
    RowLayout{

        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter

        SubmitButton {
            id: searchTitleButton

            onClicked:{
                biTitle.running = true;
                recipeFetcher.searchByTitle(titleText.text);
            }
        }

        BusyIndicator{
            implicitWidth: 50 * Math.min(root.width * 0.002, root.height * 0.002)
            implicitHeight: implicitWidth 
            id: biTitle
            running: false
        }
    }
```